# check equality of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm coming from c++ background so i never experienced this issue before; in javascript im simply trying to check for equality between two strings and am having some trouble. For example if i do:

```
...
Component.onCompleted: {

var arr = [img1]

        if(arr[0].source === "qrc:/image.png"){   //using === don't work
            console.log("ok")
        }

}

Image{
    id: img1
    width: 100
    height: 100
    source: "image.png"
}
```

nothing happens because it appears it's not evaluated to true, when it should be true. But if i use == instead, it does evaluate to true, but i get a warning of type coersion...

**UPDATE** based on the comments, It seems i need to check the type of the source first and then the string, so i try:

```
   var arr = [img1]

   console.log(typeof arr[0].source)

        if(typeof arr[0].source === Object){
            if(arr[0].source === "qrc:/image.png"){
                console.log("ok")
            }
        }
```

But the first check is false, although it is an object... Still not working.

**SOLVED**

I just needed to call toString() on source to enable strict type and value comparison:

```
  var arr = [img1]

            if(arr[0].source.toString() === "qrc:/image.png"){
                console.log("ok")
            }
```

Thanks to all that helped...

Comment: === checks for value and data type.  == checks for value and will attempt to compare even if types are not exactly the same

Comment: When using == you will get a type coersion warning as arr[I].source is of unknown type. It is not guaranteed to be a string. === won't allow type coersion so it returns false.  Side note. == is equal value, but === is equal type and value.  If you checked the typr of source first and then compared it would be true

Comment: Only way `"qrc:/image.png"` would ever be equal to `"image.png"` would be if `.source` referenced an object that had a `.toString()` method that did some processing on the string to add the `"qrc:/"`. You show `.source` referencing a string literal. Need more info.

Comment: Why do you expect `"qrc:/image.png" === "image.png"` (regardless of `===` or `==`)?

Comment: First step would be to do `console.log(typeof arr[i].source);` and see if you get "object" or "string".

Comment: @squint - the image is loaded from qml.qrc file...

Comment: Arrays store string values differently from plain string primitives. You should be using == for string equality. Or not at all. Wonder why were you checking for string equality at all.